# Where can I see procedure in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, procedure

Where can I see procedure in MYSQL?
I tried to write procedure in MYSQL but I did not found where I see existing procedure,
It show me only tabels,

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`

[Manual page here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-status.html)